# How to add a thumbnail for wordpress in an rss feed

Tags: php, wordpress

I am hosted by hostinger or I have a wordpress site with its own database.
I also have another site made in html php in a subdomain.
I would like to be able to display a wordpress rss feed with a thumbnail on my site in php / html.

So I have a page that I host on my site in php / html which allows me to collect the title, a link and the description, but I would have liked to add the thumbnail.

```
<?php
if($flux = simplexml_load_file('http://clone.pecheperle.be/category/material/feed/'))
{
    $donnee = $flux->channel;
    
    // Initialiser le compteur.
    $compteur = 0;
    // Affiche les 5 derniers articles.
    $limite = 5;

    foreach($donnee->item as $valeur)
    {
        echo '<p>'.date("d/m/Y",strtotime($valeur->pubDate)).'';
        echo ' - <a target="_blank" href="'.$valeur->link.'">'.$valeur->title.'</a>';
        echo ' '.$valeur->description.'</p>';

        // Le compteur incrémente +1 à chaque affichage.
        $compteur++;
        // Arrête d'afficher les articles quand la valeur limite est atteinte.
        if ($compteur == $limite)
        break;
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Le flux RSS du site  n\'a pas pu être chargé.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thumbnails are not part of the default feed/RSS definition; But you can extend its format with the media specification ( see https://www.rssboard.org/media-rss ).

So you have to add one or more media:content tags into the items of the feed. In WP you usually have more as one image size (medium, large, post-thumbnail, ...), so you add all you need. So it would look like this:

```
<media:content url="http://DOMAIN/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2021/11/sampleimage-300x195.jpg" 
     medium="image" width="300" height="195" type="image/jpeg" >
<media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[medium]]></media:description> 
 </media:content>
 <media:content url="http://DOMAIN/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2021/11/sampleimage-1024x666.jpg"
     medium="image" width="1024" height="666" type="image/jpeg" >
 <media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[large]]></media:description> 
 </media:content>
 <media:content url="http://DOMAIN/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2021/11/sampleimage-231x150.jpg" 
     medium="image" width="231" height="150" type="image/jpeg" >
 <media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[post-thumbnail]]></media:description> 
 </media:content>
```

To add this in wordpress you have to create a plugin for this or add it in your theme.

```php
<?php 
public function add_media_thumbnail() {
      global $post;
       
      if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) {
           $thumb_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
           $data = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $thumb_ID ); 
             $details = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_ID, 'full');  
           $size = @filesize( get_attached_file( $thumb_ID ) );
             echo '<enclosure url="' . $details[0] . '" length="' . $size . '" type="image/jpg" />' . "\n";
 
    foreach ( $data['sizes'] as $_size => $sizedata) {
        $details = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_ID, $_size);
        $out = '';    
        if( is_array($details) ) {
            if ( in_array( $_size, array('thumbnail') ) ) {
            $out .= '<media:thumbnail url="'.$details[0]. '" width="' . $details[1] . '" height="' . $details[2] . '" />' . "\n";        
            } else {
            
    
                if ( in_array( $_size, $options['filter_sizes'] ) ) {
                $out .= '<media:content url="'.$details[0].'" medium="image" width="'.$details[1].'" height="'.$details[2].'" type="'.$sizedata['mime-type'].'" >';
                $out .= '<media:description type="plain"><![CDATA['.$_size.']]></media:description>';
                $out .= ' </media:content>';
                $out .= "\n";
                }
        
            }
           echo $out;       
        }

    }

      }
    }
    
     // add the namespace to the RSS opening element
    public function add_media_namespace() {
          echo "xmlns:media=\"".$options['add_namespace']."\"";
    }
    
    ?>
```

Then enhance the default actions for rss with the functions:

```
 public function do_thumbnails2rss() {
    add_action( 'rss2_ns', 'add_media_namespace' );
    add_action( 'rss2_item', 'add_media_thumbnail' );
 }
```

After this you can parse the feed and get the thumbnail in the size you need.

Comment: Hello
a very big thank you for the code and for the explanation. it's really super nice